# Passing external elements to the model in a select query with Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

Trying to transform a query in raw mysql to the eloquent laravel queries. I am stuck on trying to get external elements (from other models) inside it...Mainly the "color" (that comes from the BookingStatus and creating the URL and putting it in as URL. 
Could you help me out?

Here is the mysql query:

```
$booking = DB::table('bookings')
                        ->select('bookings.id as id', 'booking_reference as description', 'booking_status as title', 'color', DB::raw('concat("http://127.0.0.1/blabla/public/profile/Calendar/detail/",bookings.id) as url'),'booking_date as start')
                        ->join('booking_status','booking_status.id','=','bookings.bookingstatus_id')
                        ->where('photographer_id', '=', $photographer->id)
                        ->union(DB::table('bookings')
                            ->select('bookings.id as id', 'booking_reference as description', 'booking_status as title', 'color',DB::raw('concat("http://127.0.0.1/KYMA/public/profile/Calendar/detail/",bookings.id) as url'),'booking_date as start')
                            ->join('booking_status','booking_status.id','=','bookings.bookingstatus_id')
                            ->where('user_client_id', '=', $user->id)
                        )
                        ->get();
```

edited: And here is where I have gone so far

```
$booking_info = Booking::with('bookingStatus')
                        ->where('photographer_id', $photographer->id)
                        ->orWhere('user_client_id', $user->id)
                        ->select(['id as id', 'booking_reference as description','booking_date as start', 'bookingstatus_id as title'])
                        ->get();
```

I tried a few things with the color and read the docs of Laravel but I just can't get it right... How do I pass it in my select query ? If I simply add 'color' obviously it will not pick it up because it is in the attached array and not the "primary" one...

Thanks a lot for your help!!

///// EDIT ///// 
Here is a solution I found to be able to pass everything I want, I'm not using the model relations thought since couldn't understand how to pass their array values in my select request...

```
                $booking_info = Booking::where('photographer_id', $photographer->id)
                        ->orWhere('user_client_id', $user->id) //because he could be client of a shoot ;-)
                        ->join('booking_status','booking_status.id','=','bookings.bookingstatus_id')
                        ->join('shooting_types', 'shooting_types.id', '=', 'bookings.stype_id')
                        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'user_client_id')
                        ->join('addresses', 'addresses.id', '=', 'users.address_id')
                        ->select('bookings.id as id', 'first_name', 'phonenumber', 'booking_reference as description', 'stype_name as title', 'color', 'booking_date as start')
                        ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
$bookings = Booking::with('booking_status')
                   ->where('photographer_id', $photographer->id)
                   ->orWhere('user_client_id', $user->id)
                   ->get();
```

of course you need to have `status` relationship between `Booking` and `Status`

And if you have `color` column in your `BookingStatus` model, you can access it now:

```
foreach ($bookings as $b) {
  echo $b->booking_status->color;
}
```

Comment: @commandantp You should probably define it this way: `return $this->belongsTo('BookingStatus','bookingstatus_id'); `

Comment: @commandantp You should probably ask another question about url, because there is nothing in your question about url explaining what you have tried and what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: Thanks man, I appreciate your help! Ok well basically is there a Laravel way of doing that? DB::raw('concat("http://127.0.0.1/blabla/public/profile/Calendar/detail/",bookings.id) as url') 
:-)

Comment: I cannot read it (it's not full), comments are not good place to put code or ask new questions.

Comment: True, I will ask a separate one for this. Thanks, however I still haven't solved the original question: in my select query how do I pass the 'color'? If I just call select('color') it won't return it as it is in the bookingStatus array... and I can't seem to pass a query in the select query itself....

Comment: Thanks, I know how to access it aside. But how do I pass it in my select query? I need to return an array with all the infos on a booking including the "color" for all of them that I will then transform in Json. I edited the main question too with the new code

Comment: @commandantp It's just enought to do return `$bookings` - you will have there also booking_status and will be able to read color as I showed

Comment: Thank you so much for helping man! Almost there! :-) ok so with return I get an array but I still have not been able to select which datas I want to output and their names. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Using Raw SQL is not suggested as long as Model core api can be invoked directly in controller by having related associations with other table. I would suggest to use Models core api with relations.

For Example

```
$bookings = Booking::with('booking_status')
                   ->where('photographer_id', $photographer->id)
                   ->get();
```

The above sample code is just an example of using laravel eloquent associations in controller. However, you will need to make changes in the above conditions as per your requirement.

**Note:** The above code will work only if you have defined associations in all relevant models. For example Booking model must have association "hasMany" with BookingStatus model and similarly BookingStatus model should have association "belongsTo" with Booking table. In this way you don't need to write custom queries.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Indeed I have set all the associations and use them extensively. But from what you wrote could I just do that then: Booking->bookingStatus()/*this is the relationship btwn models*/->user()->photographer()->select('blabla as bloblo', 'color', etc...)->get ??

Comment: I am not sure if select("bla bla") can be executed after method name of related association but will need to check. You can check it if it gives any error